# Discuss Advantages of multiple endpoints in WCF service

Tags: wcf, servicecontract

**One guy explained this way but not very clear to how to implement it.**

From experience:

Using different binding, for example one BasicHttpBinding for Java clients while using WsHttpBinding for .NET clients. Also HTTPS for some and HTTP for others...

Dividing and exposing different contracts/interfaces. For example you have one interface that exposes many operations and you have a cut down interface which does basic things and you publish the second to outside so internal clients use the endpoint for extended interface but external clients use the other one.

For example

```
interface IFoo
{
   void DoBasic();  
}

interface IFooInternal : IFoo
{
   void DoMore();  
}

Now you have One class implementing both:

public class Foo : IFooInternal 
{
    ....
}
```

And now you expose only one to outside while implementation is in the same class.

the things which i do not understand how to design my service contract in such a way that few operation i will expose to other client and extended feature i will expose to internal client. so if possible just make me understand giving me a small program & code that how it can be possible through multiple endpoints in WCF service. thanks